# paypal sandbox account return url issue

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I had done paypal sandbox account in my project and it was working fine but the only issue am facing is that once I set up the return url also they didn’t return back to my account after finishing the payment,and I tried that option once again to set return url using sandbox account,but they shows a message that that provision is outdated now ,so I am in a great confusion that how could I return url to my site after finishing the payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the return URL after payment is completed, you need to turn on the option in your account. You can follow the step below as the Auto Return is actually is off by default. I've list the step in for the new layout of PayPal ;

1. Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com. My Account Overview page appears.
2. Click the Profile subtab. The Profile Summary page appears.
3. Click the My Selling Tools link in the left column.
4. Under the Selling Online section, click the Update link in the row for Website Preferences. The Website Payment Preferences page appears.
5. Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
6. In the Return URL field, enter the URL to which you want your payers redirected after they complete their payments. NOTE: PayPal checks the Return URL that you enter. If the URL is not properly formatted or cannot be validated, PayPal will not activate Auto Return.
7. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the Save button.

One more thing that you need to know is that if the payment is done via the Credit/debit card, the Auto Return will not work too.